# How to use bracket symbol in node name in forest?

Tags: tikz-trees, forest

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{forest}

\begin{document}
\begin{forest}
[Z [$K[2]$] ]
\end{forest}
\end{document}
```

How can I use brackets in a node name? Not necessarily inside math. The above just yiels weird errors.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

From [page 4 of the `forest` documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/graphics/pgf/contrib/forest/forest-doc.pdf#page=4) or Ex. (4), "If you need a square bracket as part of a node’s content, use braces." To view the documentation for a package, try `texdoc <package name>` from a command line.

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{forest}
\begin{document}
\begin{forest}
[Z [{$K[2]$}] ]
\end{forest}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Oh gee... I looked into the manual but only searched for escaping etc. Thanks! :)